# Java SWT - Parent and Child Dialog Communication

Tags: java, swt, swtbot

I am trying to set up a "parent-child" dialog relationship where I want to enter in information on the child dialog (say in a textbox) and allow that information to be displayed (or transferred) to the parent dialog (say on a label) where it can be saved as a String int etc

Is there a way to do this?  Any code samples would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the "child" closed before you want to show that information on the "parent"?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference to the parent in the dialog constructor method. Then implementing the methods you need in your parent you can pass any data to it.